# python use different versions of six module

Tags: python

there are two versions of six module that need to be used
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

1 version is used by urllib module
1 version is used by retrying module

instead of having the python libraries (including: urllib, retrying) in site-packages directory, 
in my development environment, all of the python libraries are on a network drive so that all the runtime environments are using the same libraries.

how can i get the retrying module to use one version of six and the urllib module to use another version of six?  thanks

Comment: Is some newer version of six really not backwards compatible? If so, that's... horrible.

Comment: only the old version is getting referenced, but i want the new version to be referenced when running the retrying module